# .NET Object mapping, grouping objects

Tags: .net, automapper, valueinjecter

Lets say that I have a list of objects like so:

```
public class FlatModel
{
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public decimal value1 { get; set; }
    public decimal value2 { get; set; }
    public decimal value3 { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to map them to the following object, by grouping based on GroupName

```
public class GroupedModel
{
    public string groupName { get; set; }
    public List<ModelValues> values { get; set; }
}

public class ModelValues
{
    public decimal value1 { get; set; }
    public decimal value2 { get; set; }
    public decimal value3 { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a straight-forward way to do this using Automapper, Value Injector, or some other object mapping utility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can it work for you?

```
        var arr = new List<FlatModel>();

        var result = from p in arr
                     group p by p.groupName into g
                     select 
                         new GroupedModel { 
                             groupName = g.Key, 
                             values = (from q in g 
                                                select 
                                                    new ModelValues { 
                                                        value1 = q.value1, 
                                                        value2 = q.value2, 
                                                        value3 = q.value3 }).ToList() 
                         };
```

Comment: Thanks, that definitely pointed me in the right direction. I haven't used Linq very extensively, but it seems to be quite useful for this task.